# printk outputs only timestamp and does not print the message

Tags: c, linux-kernel, printk

I can't see any effect of the `printk` except the timestamp:

[image]

The first line was printed by the `dev_xxx` macro in a driver.

The print (I simply want to see the converted values as I have some problems with it)

```
void touchscreen_report_pos(struct input_dev *input,
                const struct touchscreen_properties *prop,
                unsigned int x, unsigned int y,
                bool multitouch)
{
    touchscreen_apply_prop_to_x_y(prop, &x, &y);
    printk(KERN_WARNING, "AFTER: x:%u y:%u\n", x, y); 
    input_report_abs(input, multitouch ? ABS_MT_POSITION_X : ABS_X, x);
    input_report_abs(input, multitouch ? ABS_MT_POSITION_Y : ABS_Y, y);
}
```

Settings

```
root@myboard:~# cat /proc/sys/kernel/printk
7       4       1       7
```

`printk` enabled in kernel configuration:

[image]

Any clues?

Comment: Does it execute whatever comes next? Maybe it is just stuck printing it because of some UB?

Comment: @EugeneSh. Yes, it does

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yes silly error, thank you. Post the answer I will accept it. I read the documentation, simply forgot about this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [the documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/next/core-api/printk-basics.html) say:

> the log level is **not** a separate argument

<sub>[Emphasis mine]</sub>

Since you pass the loglevel as a separate argument, that will be the whole format string, and nothing will be printed.

Change to

```
printk(KERN_WARNING "AFTER: x:%u y:%u\n", x, y); 
//                 ^
// Note no comma here
```